# Embedding PyQtGraph plots within an existing Qt Window

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to embed PyQtGraphs into an existing Qt Window (designed with Qt Designer and converted to .py file). I'm having trouble getting the PyQt GraphicLayoutView to size correctly to the Qt Group which is also inside a Tab.

I had previously managed to get the plots to work using MatPlotLib but they are just too slow at updating once the dataset gets larger, so i decided to make the switch to PyQtGraph as several posts suggested.

Im unsure if im embedding the plots correctly or if it is a case of resizing the GrahpicLayoutView to fill the group.

Any help is appreciated, code and images attached:

[Image showing how the graphicsView doesnt size to fit the group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIxcY.png)

emgWindow_ui.py

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'emgWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        global win,curve
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(1239, 796)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setMargin(11)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.recordTab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.recordTab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("recordTab"))
        self.dirFrame = QtGui.QFrame(self.recordTab)
        self.dirFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 640, 711, 51))
        self.dirFrame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.dirFrame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.dirFrame.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dirFrame"))
        self.dirTextBox = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.dirFrame)
        self.dirTextBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 511, 31))
        self.dirTextBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dirTextBox"))
        self.recordBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.dirFrame)
        self.recordBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 10, 81, 31))
        self.recordBtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("recordBtn"))
        self.stopBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.dirFrame)
        self.stopBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 10, 81, 31))
        self.stopBtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stopBtn"))
        self.trainingIMGBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.recordTab)
        self.trainingIMGBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 400, 481, 291))
        self.trainingIMGBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("trainingIMGBox"))
        self.IMUBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.recordTab)
        self.IMUBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 10, 481, 381))
        self.IMUBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("IMUBox"))
        self.EMGBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.recordTab)
        self.EMGBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 711, 621))
        self.EMGBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("EMGBox"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.recordTab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.classifyTab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.classifyTab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("classifyTab"))
        self.frame_4 = QtGui.QFrame(self.classifyTab)
        self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 921, 681))
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("frame_4"))
        self.featuresBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.classifyTab)
        self.featuresBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 261, 191))
        self.featuresBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("featuresBox"))
        self.MAVCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.MAVCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 141, 17))
        self.MAVCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MAVCheck"))
        self.RMSCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.RMSCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 141, 17))
        self.RMSCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("RMSCheck"))
        self.VARCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.VARCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 131, 17))
        self.VARCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("VARCheck"))
        self.SSICheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.SSICheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 141, 17))
        self.SSICheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SSICheck"))
        self.ZCCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.ZCCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 131, 17))
        self.ZCCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("ZCCheck"))
        self.WLCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.WLCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 141, 17))
        self.WLCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("WLCheck"))
        self.SSCCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.SSCCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 141, 17))
        self.SSCCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("SSCCheck"))
        self.WACheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.featuresBox)
        self.WACheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 160, 131, 17))
        self.WACheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("WACheck"))
        self.splitBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.classifyTab)
        self.splitBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 261, 91))
        self.splitBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("splitBox"))
        self.trainSpin = QtGui.QSpinBox(self.splitBox)
        self.trainSpin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 42, 22))
        self.trainSpin.setMinimum(1)
        self.trainSpin.setMaximum(100)
        self.trainSpin.setSingleStep(5)
        self.trainSpin.setProperty("value", 70)
        self.trainSpin.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("trainSpin"))
        self.testSpin = QtGui.QSpinBox(self.splitBox)
        self.testSpin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 42, 22))
        self.testSpin.setMinimum(1)
        self.testSpin.setMaximum(100)
        self.testSpin.setSingleStep(5)
        self.testSpin.setProperty("value", 30)
        self.testSpin.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("testSpin"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.splitBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 91, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.splitBox)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 91, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.splitBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.splitBox)
        self.splitBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 20, 75, 61))
        self.splitBtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("splitBtn"))
        self.trainBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.classifyTab)
        self.trainBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 310, 181, 41))
        self.trainBtn.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.trainBtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("trainBtn"))
        self.resultsBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.classifyTab)
        self.resultsBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 360, 261, 331))
        self.resultsBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("resultsBox"))
        self.resultsScroll = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.resultsBox)
        self.resultsScroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 241, 301))
        self.resultsScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.resultsScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.resultsScroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.resultsScroll.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("resultsScroll"))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 222, 299))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"))
        self.resultsScroll.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.classifyTab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.testTab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.testTab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("testTab"))
        self.detectBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.testTab)
        self.detectBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 10, 191, 681))
        self.detectBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("detectBox"))
        self.gestureTable = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.detectBox)
        self.gestureTable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 171, 651))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.gestureTable.setFont(font)
        self.gestureTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.gestureTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.gestureTable.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.gestureTable.setTextElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideMiddle)
        self.gestureTable.setRowCount(10)
        self.gestureTable.setColumnCount(1)
        self.gestureTable.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gestureTable"))
        self.gestureTable.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.gestureTable.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(170)
        self.gestureTable.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.gestureTable.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(65)
        self.imgBox = QtGui.QFrame(self.testTab)
        self.imgBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 581, 571))
        self.imgBox.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.imgBox.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.imgBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("imgBox"))
        self.gestureSignal = QtGui.QLabel(self.testTab)
        self.gestureSignal.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 590, 581, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.gestureSignal.setFont(font)
        self.gestureSignal.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.gestureSignal.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gestureSignal"))
        self.startBtn = QtGui.QPushButton(self.testTab)
        self.startBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 630, 71, 51))
        self.startBtn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startBtn"))
        self.stopBtn_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.testTab)
        self.stopBtn_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 630, 75, 51))
        self.stopBtn_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stopBtn_2"))
        self.currentBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.testTab)
        self.currentBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 10, 411, 681))
        self.currentBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("currentBox"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.testTab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1239, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(self.EMGBox)
        #self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow()

        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.p6 = self.win.addPlot(title="My Plot")
        self.curve = self.p6.plot(pen='r')

        data1 = np.random.normal(size=300)
        curve1 = self.p6.plot(data1)
        ptr1 = 0
        def update1():
            global data1, ptr1
            data1[:-1] = data1[1:]  # shift data in the array one sample left
                                    # (see also: np.roll)
            data1[-1] = np.random.normal()
            curve1.setData(data1)

            ptr1 += 1
            curve1.setData(data1)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "EMG Gesute Classifier", None))
        self.recordBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Record", None))
        self.stopBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop", None))
        self.trainingIMGBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Gesture", None))
        self.IMUBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "IMU Data", None))
        self.EMGBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "EMG Data", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.recordTab), _translate("MainWindow", "Record", None))
        self.featuresBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Features", None))
        self.MAVCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Mean Absolute Value", None))
        self.RMSCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Root Mean Square", None))
        self.VARCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Variance", None))
        self.SSICheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Simple Square Integral", None))
        self.ZCCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Zero Crossings", None))
        self.WLCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Wave Length", None))
        self.SSCCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Slope Sign Changes", None))
        self.WACheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Willison Amplitude", None))
        self.splitBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Split Data", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Training Dataset:", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test Dataset:", None))
        self.splitBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Split", None))
        self.trainBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Train", None))
        self.resultsBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Results", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.classifyTab), _translate("MainWindow", "Classify", None))
        self.detectBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Gesture Detected", None))
        self.gestureSignal.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SIGNAL", None))
        self.startBtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start", None))
        self.stopBtn_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop", None))
        self.currentBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Current", None))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.testTab), _translate("MainWindow", "Test", None))
```

It is all executed from emgRun.py

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from emgesture import EMG_Classify as emg

from emgWindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

data = emg.dataset

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```